# English analog to "Stelzbock" or why so few sexual cusses for men?

Tags: history, gender, political-correctness

german female version of *Stelzbock* someone told me would be *Flittchen* - *Hussy* (eng). Is there an appropriate translation? Imo, *Macho* and *Gigolo* doesn't match , to less animal-like and more a lifestyle. *Male hussy* or *manwhore* seem quite common, but are more abusing women as a group than a single man if you think about it :)

There seem to be a lot slang words describing sexual behaviour of women, but much less for men. Should be quite the opposite ;) Are the more political gender correct cusses concerning sexual behaviour for men in German? Or is this phenomenon a relict of our mostly patriarchal social history, that there are generally more cusses (not only sexual-related) for women? Are there studies viewing this discrimation of women via language. Makes me think of *Hexe* too, what's the male analogon?

Comment: What about "lecher"?

Comment: @Stefan *lecher-wüstling* imo that doesnt match well. *Wüstling* for me is someone not normal developed sexually, maybe with a fetish(?) *Stelzbock* i would translate to somebody actively dating and looking for women but lacking good behaviour? I dont really know a god analog, *manwhore* seems correct but derived from the female cuss...

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. From your question it seems that English is your mother tongue (or at least a language you know better than German), yet you try to understand the meaning of "lecher" by looking at the German translation from some dictionary. If you know the meaning of the German word, this question should be on English SE, shouldn't it?

Comment: @stefan this site is about Q&A, not people, i try to forumalte questions so that they seem interesting & helping not only for me personally. This should be the goal imho of a BETA........ On topic: Do you think *Wüstling* and *Stelzbock* match? A *Wüstling* looks much more out of control to me ;) He dont has to have a intention of dating women, imo fine but crucial distinction

Comment: I don't think they match. "Stelzbock" is not a word I or people I know normally use. So I could be wrong. But to me "Stelzbock" has the narrower meaning of an older man who tries to get sexual favors from young women through money, trickery or mental pressure.

Comment: This seems to be a sociology/cultural question and where it does become a language question it's asking about English in comparison to already known terms in German, not asking about German. As such it seems to belong more on english L&U than here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other words could be:

- [Schürzenjäger](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/sch%C3%BCrzenj%C3%A4ger)
- [Weiberheld](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/weiberheld)
- [Frauenheld](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/frauenheld)  (similar to Weiberheld)
- Casanova: this was actually a man that had many sexual relationships.
  But we use his name to call someone (in a more positive than negative
  way) who behaves like Casanova did.

Duden also suggests Charmeur, Ladykiller, Weiberer and Womanizer as synonyms for Frauenheld.

Comment: Now that I read this again I might have understood the question wrong.

Comment: thx. You answered partly, but im still very interested why there are no original cusses for men, but mostly derivations of female ones. That really surprised me. Imo *womanizer* is good but more meaning someone who could have any woman. A *Stelzbock* doesnt have to be very successful ;) and mostly will not be :) Also Stelzbock is a cuss imo but FrauenHELD of course not.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not which gender's behavior was "looser," or worse, but which gender's behavior was less TOLERATED.

A woman can bear a child by her "man" even if he is seeing other woman. On the other hand, only one man can produce a child with a given woman at one time. Therefore, a woman's "misbehavior" infringed on her mate's rights far more than his behavior would infringe on hers.

Which is why men were always obsessed with the behavior, good or otherwise, of women. And women much less so with men.